# TCPClient connects to Gmail but does not receive first message

Tags: c#, ssl, gmail, tcpclient, gmail-imap

I am using this code to connect to gmail. Every WriteLine() is written. So presumably everything worked correctly? However no message is written to the console. What is wrong?
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;

namespace RemoteControl
{
class MailClient
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // create an instance of TcpClient 
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting...");
            TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
            tcpclient.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993);
            SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream());
            sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("imap.gmail.com");
            Console.WriteLine("Reached Gmail.");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sslstream);
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslstream);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending username.");
            sw.WriteLine("USER user@gmail.com");
            Console.WriteLine("Sending password.");
            sw.WriteLine("PASS pass");
            Console.WriteLine("Receiving Message.");
            sw.WriteLine("RETR 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Complete.");
            tcpclient.Close(); // close the connection
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1. The streams, streamreaders and streamwriters (and maybe tcpclient) should be in `using` blocks. 2. What if a different exception were thrown? 3. `finally {Console.ReadLine();}`

Comment: Your reader never actually appears to read anything.

Comment: Err, call a read method? Not a real question.

Answer (score 0):

**  Based on my understanding your issue was wanted to read the emails using C#. If it's true I think socket pop3 was a good choice to solve your issue. For exmaple: **

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create an instance of TcpClient 
    TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
    tcpclient.Connect("pop3.live.com", 995);
    System.Net.Security.SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream());
    sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop3.live.com");
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sslstream);
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslstream);
    sw.WriteLine("USER xxx@live.com"); sw.Flush();
    sw.WriteLine("PASS xxxx****"); sw.Flush();
    sw.WriteLine("RETR 1");
    sw.Flush();
    sw.WriteLine("Quit ");
    sw.Flush();
    string str = string.Empty;
    string strTemp = string.Empty;
    while ((strTemp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (".".Equals(strTemp))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (strTemp.IndexOf("-ERR") != -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        str += strTemp;
    }
    Response.Write(str);
    reader.Close();
    sw.Close();
    tcpclient.Close(); // close the connection
}
}
```